# Louse coupling and java buttons

Tags: java, loose-coupling

I am reading a book and it gives an example on loose coupling:

> As an example take Javas buttons, where you take and assign a button
>   listener to the buttons of the existing type without having to change
>   anything in the existing button class.

I am not sure I understand what the author means. How is that an example of loose coupling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coupling is loose because the Button doesn't know anything about your specific ButtonListener implementation. And conversely, the ButtonListener doesn't know very much about the Button. The ButtonListener interface only provides you with an Event - encapsulating the information you need to know about what changed. Your implementation is limited in its awareness of the type of the source of that event. So, your listener and the button never directly talk to each other using their class-level API elements, they only talk to each other in terms of the interfaces which they implement - ButtonListener and Event. Broadly speaking, when two classes communicate with each other through a shared abstract API they're described as loosely-coupled - meaning that neither of them depend on implementation-specific details of the other and so their internals can change independently.